# How to correct the output of a function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

I'm writing a function that will return the total cost of a trip, but I keep getting the wrong output whenever I put "Charlotte" and any number as arguments for the trip_cost function. When I put trip_cost('Charlotte', 6) for example, the software that checks for the right answer keeps telling me that the function produces 1240 instead of 1243.

Can anyone give me tips on how to correct the following code?

```
def hotel_cost(nights):
    cost = 140 * nights
    return cost

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte": 
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = 40 * days
    if days >= 7:
        cost -= 50
    elif days >= 3 and days < 7:
        cost -= 20
    return cost

def trip_cost(city, days):
    total = rental_car_cost(days) + hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) 
    return total
```

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Glad to see it worked, thought maybe I had messed up one of the other functions somehow. Perhaps there's a bug in the answer checking software.

Comment: By the way, you can shorten `days >= 3 and days < 7` to `3 <= days < 7`. It's called a *chained comparison* (https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).